# Ruby on Rails - Combine and Sort two different activerecord queries

Tags: sorting, ruby-on-rails-4

I have two different active record queries that I am combining into one query.  The queries is of two different tables, and has different column names.  Once I combine the two queries together, I want to be able to sort it be one of the rows that contains a date.  However, in "Query1" the date is called startdate.  In "Query2", the date is called starts_at.  I was hoping to be able to use a select alias for the Query1 to return startdate as starts_at, but after spending two days exhausting that option with no resolution (apparently select as doesn't work), I am hoping there is a way to sort the combined queries short of having to write my own sorting method.

As an example, the code I am using is similar to:

```
@Query1 = Course.select(:id,:city,:start_date).where(...)
@Query2 = Workshop.select(:id,:topic,:starts_at).where(...)

@CombinedQuery = Query1 + Query2
```

I want to sort @CombinedQuery so that the dates are of ascending order, but in a way that the results of Query1 and Query2 are sorted together.  Is there any easy way of doing this?

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To sort your `@CombinedQuery` in Ruby, here's a way:

```
@CombinedQuery.sort_by do |record|
  if record.respond_to? :startdate
    record.startdate
  elsif record.respond_to? :starts_at
    record.starts_at
  end
end
```

A side note: If you want to follow ruby naming conventions, then you should rename `@Query1` and `@Query1` to lowercase `@query1` and `@query2` respectively. The `@CombinedQuery` should be changed to snakecase `@combined_query`